# Disable welcome email to employees on at Community

Tags: community

We have a support community used by internal employees and customers.
Every time a new user is registered, the system sends a welcome email.
While we want to keep sending this message to customers, we would like to disable it for employees.
In  the future we might want to have 2 different emails, one for customers and one for employees.

Questions:
1 -  How can we disable it for employees? All have the same email domain
2 -  How can have use different messages for external customers and employees?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Under community management, you can disable this feature
[image]

Afterwards, you can send a welcome email based on the Profile that created an account using the process [builder](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=process_overview.htm)